# Can't get Facebook friend's birthdays from Android app

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

I'm trying to get birthday dates of my friends from my Android application, here's the code I'm using:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("fields", "name, picture, birthday");
friends = facebook.request("me/friends", params);
```

I'm getting the list of friends containing names, ids, and pictures, but there's only one out of a hundred friends returned with a birthday. I added the friends_birthday permission in the Auth_dialog section of facebook Developer.
Most of the people have birthdays defined when I look at them from Facebook, but I can't get them from my Android app.

I'm guessing there's some problem with permissions, but I can't understand why I can see the birthday of this one friend...

Am I missing something?

Comment: Solved: needed to specify permissions when authorizing:
public static String [] FacebookPermissions = new String [] {"friends_birthday"};facebook.authorize(this, FacebookPermissions, MyDialogListener);.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest ensure you have the correct permissions requested from the user.  To verify you can use the linter tool (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint) to see what permissions you have. Or you can check programmatically by calling `/me/permissions`.

Permissions documentation is https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/

You'll need at minimum: `friends_birthday`

Remember, you won't always get full information on the birthdays.  Some are full birthday with month, day and year.  While others can be month and day only.  Some can even be blank/null.